# Pointer Behaviour in C: Initializing Linked List Head after Node

Tags: c, pointers

I am a little puzzled by this C behaviour. If I initialize the "head" pointer after the node it seems that it does not continue holding on to the next elements. Sample code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    node* head = NULL;
    node* current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->value = 1;

    if(head == NULL)
        head = current;

    current = current->next;

    current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->value = 2;

    printf("%d\n", current->value); // 2
    printf("%d\n", head->value); // 1
    printf("%d\n", head->next->value); //Segmentation fault: 11, Should be 2

    return 0;

}
```

As far as I understand: I malloc() memory for current, then set the value. Then set head equal to current. They now both point to the same node.

Then I make current = current->next, malloc memory and set the value.

Why does head->next->value not point to the same place as current->value?

Comment: You never set `next`, anywhere.  Not in current, not in head.  Its value is undefined, quite likely zero.  So you cannot attempt to dereference it.

Comment: 'current = current->next;current = malloc(sizeof(node));'  look at those two statements - one must be incorrect, since the second overwrites the value loaded by the first.

Comment: @TomKarzes Do I not set 'next' after I make 'current = current->next' and then malloc it memory? At this point, shouldn't 'current->next' and 'head->next' be the same thing?

Comment: @MartinJames `current` is a pointer though, so setting `current = current->next` makes `current` point to where `current->next` was pointing. After that I allocate the memory, so nothing get's overwritten.

Comment: @teafellow when you use `malloc` it's going to choose the pointer's location and return it to the variable. It's not going to create memory at the location your pointer currently is. That would require knowing where the memory was available beforehand.

Comment: No, you don't.  `current = current->next` *reads* the (undefined) `next` field.  Remember, assignments evaluate the *right* side, and assign the result to the *left* side.

Comment: If you want to set the `next` field, you must have an assignment such as `current->next = something`.

Comment: 'current = current->next makes current point to where current->next was pointing' - yes and, taking @TomKarzes point - that is nowhere valid, because current->next is uninitialized.  Not that it matters much, because you reassign current in the very next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
current = current->next;
```

Prior to this statement, you have this:

```
             ---------------
current ---> |   1  |   ?  |
             ---------------
```

`current` points to an area of memory big enough for a `node` where the value of `value` is 1 and the value of `next` is unknown since `malloc` returns uninitialized memory.

After this statement, `current` contains the garbage value that `current->next` contained.  When you then do this:

```
current = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You change the value of `current` to whatever `malloc` returned, overwriting the prior value.

To do what you intended, you would need to do this:

```
current->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
current = current->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create 2 nodes that are linked you need to save the first's `next` to the second node.

Change

```
current = current->next;

current = malloc(sizeof(node));
current->value = 2;
```

To

```
current = malloc(sizeof(node));
current->value = 2;
head->next = current;
```

That will create a new node (reusing the current pointer you've already assigned to `head`) and attach it to `head`.

In practice though you probably don't want to attach it to `head` like this as it won't work as written beyond 2. You want to create a new entry at the end of the list, the beginning of the list, or insert it in the middle of the list.